# Cannot find module 'npmlog' - windows

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs

Running windows 7 enterprise. If I run npm install I get:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'npmlog'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.
at Function.Module._load (module.js:286:25)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at \\networkdrive\user\home\AppData\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:20:13
at Object.<anonymous> (\\networkdrive\user\home\AppDate\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js76:3)
at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
```

node lives here:  H:\tools\node

npm is here: H:\tools\node\node_modules\npm

Also, if i run "grunt" I get "'grunt' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file"
but if i run grunt commands from eclipse maven run, everything works.

Do I need to add any paths to my Environment Variables? I only have edit access to USER variables.

Comment: npm install npmlog ¿?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem about a week ago on El Capitan.
I fixed it with a reinstall.
https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Comment: couldn't find solution in your links. I updated the error snapshot. I accidentally left out some details. Does showing that its trying to point to npm-cli shed any more light on what is happening?

Comment: @Anthony - just reinstall Node will fix it

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem recently and re-installing didn't work, I had to uninstall node and then manually go and delete the "npm" and "npm-cache" folders from

> C:\Users\{yourUsername}\AppData\Roaming\

I believe this folder is normally hidden, you may have to change some settings to view it.

Answer (score -1):

If you have installed node via nvm, reinstalling it with the official installer worked for me:

- delete the target version from the nvm folder `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\nvm`
- delete the link in your programms folder `C:\Programm Files\nodejs`
- install node with the official installer from [node.js download](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)